# Does there exist a compact metric space $X$ containing countably infinitely many clopen subsets?

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory, metric-spaces, compactness

From this [Clopen subsets of a compact metric space](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/369616/clopen-subsets-of-a-compact-metric-space) we know that any compact metric space $X$ contains at most countably many clopen subsets ; my question is : Does there exist a compact metric space $X$ containing countably infinitely many clopen subsets ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Consider the subset of $\mathbb R$
$$\{ \frac{1}{n} | n\in \mathbb N^*\} \cup \{0\}\;$$ which inherits a metric structure from the standard metric of $\mathbb R$. The sets $\{1/n\}$ are countably infinitely many clopen subsets.

Comment: $\{0\}$ is the only singleton  that is not open: Any neighbourhood of zero contains infinitely many points of the set.

Comment: Can someone explain why $\{1/n\}$ is open?

Comment: @Soke every point $\frac{1}{n}$ has an open interval $O$ in the reals around it such that $O$ only contains $\frac{1}{n}$ and not $0$ or any other  $\frac{1}{m}$.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma Hmm.. ok. So we're letting $\{1/n\}_{n=1}^{\infty} \cup \{0\}$ to be the compact metric space $X$. Then for $\{\frac{1}{n}\}$ to be open we require $\frac{1}{n}$ to be an interior point of $X$. This require there to be a $r > 0$ for which $N_r(\frac{1}{n}) \subset X$. I don't see why this implies $\{\frac{1}{n}\}$ is open? Am I using the wrong topology / definition?

Comment: @Soke If the sequence is called $X$, this $O$ shows that $O \cap X = \{\frac{1}{n}\} $, so by the definition of the subspace topology, $\frac{1}{n}$ is open in $X$.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma Ok so I wasn't clear on the whole subspace topology thing. Reading up on it now. So $\{1/n\}$ is the intersection of $X$ with  $N_r(1/n)$ for $r$ small, and $N_r(1/n)$ is open in $\mathbb{R}$, hence $\frac{1}{n}$ is open in the subspace topology

Comment: Instead of using the subspace topology you might as well use the (subspace) metric of $X$. For every $n\in\mathbb N^*$ and $\epsilon>0$ sufficiently small (e.g. $<1/(2n^2))$ the open $\epsilon$-neighbourhood of $1/n$ us the singleton $\{1/n\}$.

Answer (score 2):

[The Cantor set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_set) is a standard example of such a space.